# Where to host Qt based translation files

Tags: qt, open-source

I have several Qt based application that I want to open translation permission to other people, but I don't know if there's website that can do that ?

Or what do you suggest for situation like this, I think the maintainer shouldn't maintain translation files by emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manage your translation files in a repository like [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and host them on pages like [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/).